# Almost everything being marked "important" in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

About 80% of the messages I receive get marked "important". This is ridiculous. For example I have MightySMS on my phone which automatically emails me all text messages and puts them in a label called "SMS". Even though they are under this label they appear in "important". How do I change the entire rule for important? I tried selecting a few and clicking "mark as not important" but I'm not sure what affect that actually has on the rule.

How do I get fewer emails in the important label, for example podcasts I subscribed to send out emails each week shouldn't go there?

I mean the test message for setting up Outlook was marked as important.

Comment: @pnuts yes I guess so, but it appers just because it's in another label doesn't mean that it won't be in others - for example an email could be in SMS label but is also in important label. What are you thinking?

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over the "important" icon, Gmail will tell you *why* it marked the particular message as important. It could just be that you've interacted quite a bit with such messages in the past.

Mark as "not important" and Gmail will learn better how to mark these.

One thing you might want to do is if you already have a filter acting on these messages, edit the filter and check "Never mark it as important".

[image: filter step 2]

There's quite a bit of information on how Gmail decides what's important (to you) in this [Help Center article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186543).

Comment: "One thing you might want to do is if you already have a filter acting on these messages, edit the filter and check "Never mark it as important"." how do I do this? I tried following the instructions here but I couldn't see the option to "never mark as important" https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

Comment: Also when I went to the list of filters, I noticed some must be missing because there isn't one for the label "SMS" even though all SMS messages automatically end up in there.

Comment: I've added a screen shot.

Comment: Could MightySMS be putting the label on for you? That would explain why there is no filter.